# require_once() giving internal server error 500

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

This is my piece of code

```
<?php
  require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Search/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php');
  require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Search/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_YouTubeService.php');
 ?>
```

When i'm running this on my browser its giving internal server error 500. 
my directory structure is

```
/Search/index.php
/Search/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php
/Search/google-api-php-client/........all the api file
```

The apache log file says

```
"GET /Search/ HTTP/1.1" 500 276 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686)
 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/34.0.1847.116
 Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36"
```

Please help me, i'm stuck in my code. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; and show your result

Comment: echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; gives the following output /var/www

Comment: have you any dir for site?

Comment: yes its the /Search directory

Comment: You've shown us the apache access log. What does the error log say?

Comment: You should turn on `error_reporting` thats why you are welcomed with 500 Internal error instead of PHP error.

Comment: This is what i got when i turned on the error_reporting. " Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Google PHP API Client requires the CURL PHP extension' in /var/www/Search/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php:21"

Comment: Thanks all. I figured out the bug. PHP5-curl was not installed on the server so curl_init() function was giving error.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
echo __ROOT__; // add file location according this.
require_once(__ROOT__.'/Search/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php');
```

Read manual :- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

Comment: Still getting the same error. If i'm including any other php file its easily getting executed.

Comment: what the output of "__ROOT__"

Comment: __ROOT__ gives output as /var/www

Comment: i think you missing public_html dir on your server try to make a dir with named public_html and add your serach dir in it. it's default dir for server

Comment: All my other websites are working fine on this server. They all are kept in separate directory as i'm keeping this website.

Comment: is your home page accessible if not need to contact host provider cause some config missing